# C++ Array sorting, How do i put -1 at the end of my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am currently working on a C++ project I have. I am stuck on a function I have to write. The functions name is remove. The purpose of the function is to remove the value in the list at the given index by shifting all elements back one position, -1 replaced the elements at the end of the list. I have finished the shifting portion of this function, i am just stuck on how i put -1 at the end of my array. 
Here is my code:

```
void remove(int vals[], int sz, int index)
{
  for(int i = index ; i < (sz-1); ++i)
  {
   vals[i] = vals[i+1];
  }
  vals[sz - 1] = -1;



}
```

Comment: Are you sure `i + 1` is going to be valid through the whole loop?

Comment: Q: Are you sure you want to start at `index`?  Or `index-1`?  Q: You *definitely* want to stop *before* sz.  Maybe `i < (sz-1)`?  And finally, why not just `index[sz] = -1`?  Or `index[sz-1]` (depending on how you're defining "sz")?

Comment: Why do you need to shift all the elements back by one to remove one element? That's a rather misleading purpose. You might would be better off using a dynamically allocated array and removing the element if you have the knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I believe you would need:

```
void remove(int vals[], int sz, int index)
{
  //I altered your loop here as the line inside it would have accessed past the
  //end your array. I am assuming sz is the number of elements in the array
  for(int i = index ; i < sz - 1; ++i)
  {
   vals[i] = vals[i + 1]; 

  }
  //This sets the last element in your array to -1
  vals[sz - 1] = -1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: As others have said you may be better using one of the STL containers like std::vector rather than a C-style array if you want to add and remove elements.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. Its amazing how such a simple thing actually fixes it. I'm still a beginner at this. Thank you.